# Correct approach to DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, .net, domain-driven-design, repository

I'm wondering if I'm using the correct architecture in my application.

After calling an endpoint in my API, I'm currently going through the following flow:
`Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto)` => `Services.EmployeeService.Update(Service.EmployeeUpdateDto)` => `Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Entities.Employee)` => `Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee)`

To explain a but more, my API endpoint take `Api.EmployeeUpdateDto`, within the controller it's being mapped to `Services.EmployeeUpdateDto` and passed to `Services.EmployeeService.Update()`.
Within `Services.EmployeeService.Update()` it retrieves the actual db entity by Id and updates it's values, afterwards it's passed to `EmployeeRepository.Update()` which in turn calls the underlying EF db context.

For some reason my gut tells me that it's complicated with too many layers, am I missing something?

Comment: Trust your gut. Why do you need so many layers?

Comment: @AntP I get what you're saying, but when I think about it they do make sense. Using the repository I'm able to swap out the underlying ORM for something other then EF.
And with the Service layer, I'm able to encapsulate the business logic. My question was more, if I'm applying these concepts in the correct way.

Comment: Is the risk of "swapping out ORM" so big that you need to add complexity of another layer? In DDD, the behavior should be inside the entities themselves, you sure you don't have anemic domain model instead of rich domain model in your scenario?

Comment: You have to rewrite the same code to "swap out the ORM" regardless of whether it sits in a "layer" or not.

Comment: I used to write code like this - you end up with more and more cruft and layers as things don't "fit" neatly into a particular layer, and difficult to change boundaries enforced by lots of tests with heavy use of mocks and stubs. Now what I do is inject thin DB wrappers into the root of the application (the controller, usually) and then use that to make a call for necessary data, which is then used to populate a pure domain model with no external dependencies.

Comment: @AntP I agree. I believe that too many overestimate value of abstracting out new layer and underestimating complexity of adding a new layer. My own measuring stick is how easy and simple are things to test automatically. If adding new layer is not going to make testing easier, then I just don't add it.

Comment: @Euphoric yup - unfortunately this tends to shift the difficulty from changing the code to changing the opinions of your peers...

Comment: @Euphoric Yeah I do want to clarify that I'm going for anemic domain model instead of rich domain model. That's the mainn reason for having the Service layer. My reasoning for the repositories was that I can encapsulate my multi tenancy logic there instead of on the service level.

Answer (score 3):

> Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto) => Services.EmployeeService.Update(Service.EmployeeUpdateDto) => Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Entities.Employee) => Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee

Let's look at it this way: what if you were to tell your business counterpart this? Just the above word-for-word.

I would wager he/she wouldn't have the slightest idea what you just said.

The "Domain-Driven" part of DDD means that your design decisions should be, well, driven by the domain. Its language, its structure, its behavior. The problem with your design is not just that it is complicated, but is a *technical* design, not a *domain* design.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I worded my question a bit wrong. My question was purely technical, if I'm applying an anemic domain model correctly or not.

Comment: @bimaw24064 I'm a bit confused by the idea of an anaemic domain model in DDD. The two things seem to be in contradiction.